# Vagrant up: Restarting network (via systemctl): [FAILED]

Tags: networking, vagrant

I have the following configurations in my Vagrant file.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = true
  config.vm.box = "boxcutter/centos73"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8000, guest: 8000
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.1"
end
```

This produces an error when `vagrant up`

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

# Down the interface before munging the config file. This might
# fail if the interface is not actually set up yet so ignore
# errors.
/sbin/ifdown 'eth1'
# Move new config into place
mv -f '/tmp/vagrant-network-entry-eth1-1499713004-0' '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1'
# attempt to force network manager to reload configurations
nmcli c reload || true

# Restart network
service network restart


Stdout from the command:

Restarting network (via systemctl):  [FAILED]


Stderr from the command:

usage: ifdown <configuration>
Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error 
code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl -xe" for 
details.
```

When I switch the network line to `config.vm.network "public_network"`, it works fine, why is that?

Comment: Changing the ip to 192.168.56.101 fixed it for me. As long it doesn't end with .1

Answer (score 0):

- I hope it helps...
  after 
  $ `vagrant up` command
  make sure vagrant VM is ON, regardless of error message.
- first on Host:
  $ `vagrant ssh`
- inside vagrant:
  $ `sudo apt-get install ifupdown`
- then:
  $ `sudo ifup eth1`
- Finally exit from vagrant, and execute $ `vagrant up` again on host

it worked for me!